# node.js, cannot get returned result from inner function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have done this function, using geocoder module, to get the city from a couple of lat/long:

```
// Get city from lat/long pair
function getCityFromCoordinates(lat, long){
 return geocoder.reverseGeocode(lat,long, function ( err, data ) {
    var city = "-";
    if(err){
       city = err.message;
    } else {
       if(data["results"].length == 0){ 
          city = "not found";
       } else {
          city = "";
          var first_item = data["results"][0];
          var address_components = first_item["address_components"];
          for (var i=0; i<address_components.length;i++){
             var current = address_components[i];
             var types = current["types"];
             for (var j=0;j<types.length;j++){
                var type = types[j];
                if((type == "locality") && (city == "")){
                   city = current["long_name"];
                }
             }   
          }
       }
    }
    console.log("City:" + city);
    return city;
 }); 
 }
```

When I call this function from another place, it correctly retrieve the city (I see this in the log) but it does not return the value. I'm sure this is linked to the geocoder.reserverGeocode function being embedded withing my function but I do not manage to fix this.

Comment: It looks to me like it's asynchronous code.  That means that city will be returned potentially long before it's actually set to what you want to be in the inner function.

Comment: @Corbin: `return city;` is inside the callback. It happens at the right time, but the thing that called the callback doesn't care about the returned value.

Comment: Ah! Must be getting late.  I read that as being the line after the callback.  Oops :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`geocoder.reverseGeocode` is async, which means that you can't `return` the result from inside the callback. Try something like this:

```
function getCityFromCoordinates(lat, long, cb){
 return geocoder.reverseGeocode(lat,long, function ( err, data ) {
    var city = "-";
    if(err){
       return cb(err.message);
    } else {
       if(data["results"].length == 0){ 
          return cb("not found");
       } else {
          city = "";
          var first_item = data["results"][0];
          var address_components = first_item["address_components"];
          for (var i=0; i<address_components.length;i++){
             var current = address_components[i];
             var types = current["types"];
             for (var j=0;j<types.length;j++){
                var type = types[j];
                if((type == "locality") && (city == "")){
                   city = current["long_name"];
                }
             }   
          }
       }
    }
    console.log("City:" + city);
    cb(null, city);
 }); 
}
```

Now you can use it like this in your code:

```
getCityFromCoordinates(lat, long, function(err, city) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('error: '+err);
  } else {
    console.log('result: '+city);
  }
});
```